# Elegant use of Tasks on the Unity game loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, task

I need to work with `Task`s in my Unity component. In `FixedUpdate`, I need to call an async method, which returns right away, giving me a `Task`. Whenever the `Task` completes, I also need to handle the result in (a future) `FixedUpdate` (and then repeat the process).

So my code looks roughly like this:

```
void FixedUpdate() {
  if (_task == null) {
    _task = CallAsyncMethod();
  } else if (_task.isCompleted) {
    var result = _task.Result;
    ApplyResult(result);
    _task = null;
  }
}
```

This feels like an awkward use of `Task` due to the fact that I need to handle the result on the game loop, but I can't think of anything fundamentally wrong with it.

Questions:

- Is my implementation correct and not wasteful?
- Is there a more elegant way to satisfy the same constraints? (i.e. both start a `Task` and handle its result in `FixedUpdate`)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, trying to use async patterns with Unity's update loop is an endless exercise in frustration, as it tends to spawn many edge cases.

Your best bet is to avoid async at all costs and use Coroutines instead.

If you absolutely must use async functions, consider spawning your own separate thread at the beginning of the game to manage and invoke them.  But then you have to figure out thread-safe ways to exchange data back to the main game thread.

Comment: Or look into the job system depending on what you need

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't avoid async, because I'm using a library that exposes its functionality only as async methods. I can believe that trying to use async patterns with Unity's update loop is frustrating in general, but is there anything I should be worried about in my simple example? Can you see any hidden edge cases, deadlocks, race conditions, or other unpleasant surprises?

Answer (score 0):

You could at least skip the `null` check and rather directly start a new task after the first one finished. That would make it look less "ugly" and also remove the delay of one `FixedUpdate` interval ;)

```
void Start()
{ 
    _task = CallAsyncMethod(); 
} 

void FixedUpdate() 
{ 
    if (!_task.isCompleted) return;

    var result = _task.Result;
    ApplyResult(result); 
    _task = CallAsyncMethod(); 
}
```

Or use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like e.g.

```
private IEnumerator Start ()
{
    while(true)
    {
       var task = CallAsyncMethod();
       yield return new WaitUntil(() => task.isCompleted);  
       yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
       var result = _task.Result;
       ApplyResult(result);  
    }
}
```

---

But if you really want to do async stuff in Unity in its full potential you should check out [UniTask](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask) and do e.g.

```
void Start()
{
    ApplyContinously().Forget();
}

private async UniTaskVoid ApplyContinously()
{
    while(true)
    {
        var result = await CallAsyncMethod();

        await UniTask.WaitForFixedUpdate();

        ApplyResult(result);
    }
}
```